# JavaScript Fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch

I'm, using yandex api translate to detect language from input value. First fetch return a language ui code as a string. Than i'm using another one fetch to transform that code to a name of this language (en -> english).

```
const getLang = (lang) => {
    fetch(`https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/getLangs?ui=en&key=${key}`)
        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) return response
        })
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data.langs.lang);
        })
}
```

getLang function return me undefined because lang is a string. When I',m typing "data.langs.en" in console function return "English". How can I remake my variable lang?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the property using [Property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors):

```js
const getLang = (lang) => {
    fetch(`https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/getLangs?ui=en&key=${key}`)
        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) return response
        })
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data.langs[lang]);
        });
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help! If this answer was helpful, feel free to mark it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

you must use **data.langs[lang]** in to last "then".

Answer (score -1):

try  this:

```
const getLang = (lang) => {
    fetch(`https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/getLangs?ui=en&key=${key}`)
        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) return response
        })
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data.langs[lang]);
        })
}
```